# GROUP BY on 3 columns along with IFNULL() repeating month names in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am working on a query that is meant to show the number of enquiries each month in last year for a particular salesperson.

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(c.datefield) AS month,
    YEAR(c.datefield) AS year, 
    IFNULL((
        SELECT COUNT(cc.customer_date) 
        FROM crm_customers 
        WHERE cc.customer_salesperson = 5 LIMIT 1
    ), 0) AS Enquiries 
FROM calendar AS c 
LEFT JOIN crm_customers AS cc ON c.datefield = DATE(cc.customer_date) 
WHERE YEAR(c.datefield) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
GROUP BY YEAR(c.datefield), MONTH(c.datefield), cc.customer_salesperson
```

But above query is repeating month names, not sure why?

[image]

Here is my crm_customers table:

[image]

I am joining above table with a calendar table containing one single column in date format.

How can I exclude those repeating month names?

**EDIT**

My calendar table:

[image]

Comment: why `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: could you also post `calendar` table schema?

Comment: @PeterDarmis I did, please check my updated question.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is because we need to fill value with zero for non-existing records by using a calendar table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `calendar` table is a single column table then i am only assuming that you don't run MySQL 8.0 so your query could be written as:

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(`c`.`datefield`) AS `Monthname`,
    YEAR(NOW())-1 AS `Year`,
    IFNULL(`t`.`Enquiries`,0) AS `Enquiries`
FROM `calendar` `c`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    MONTH(`cc`.`customer_date`) AS `Month`,
    YEAR(`cc`.`customer_date`) AS `Year`, 
    COUNT(`cc`.`customer_id`) AS `Enquiries` 
FROM `crm_customers` `cc`
WHERE YEAR(`cc`.`customer_date`) = YEAR(NOW())-1 
AND `cc`.`customer_salesperson`=5
GROUP BY MONTH(`cc`.`customer_date`)) `t`
ON `t`.`Month`= MONTH(`c`.`datefield`)
GROUP BY MONTH(`c`.`datefield`);
```

You can check the example in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0fb8ca/15)

Comment: Yes, I am NOT using MySQL 8.0. Rather, I am on 5.6.17. So do I need to rewrite my query totally in a new way just like you did? Can't we edit my original query to fix the bug?

Comment: Wow! that seems to be working, but can't we get my original query working correctly with some modification?

Comment: @Sachin At this point in morning and without sleep i think that is the only query my mind was able to find as a solution. Up to a point it is a modified version of your query.

Comment: Ok Peter, thanks for your help. I will try to understand it. Actually my problem is somewhere related to my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840042/query-to-get-total-orders-placed-by-some-specific-customer-in-last-year-retrieve But it is -ve marked. Can you please look into my that query so I can learn and understand a bit better?

Comment: Thanks Peter, your provided solution really helped me to sort out the query. Good job!